# How are systemd/system overrides supposed to work?

Tags: systemd, clamav, amazon-linux-2

I'm messing around with some timeout settings, and am trying to figure out the correct way to set things for systemd/system daemons. Specifically, this is an underpowered server, and I keep timing out on starting clamd, so I'm trying to figure out how high I need to set the TimeoutStartSec parameter. I tried

`systemctl edit --full clamd@.service`

and edited it to say

`TimeoutStartSec=20min`

then did `systemctl daemon-reload`

But it kept mysteriously timing out after 7 minutes. Eventually, I found that `/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamd@.service` had `TimeoutStartSec=420`.

Probably against all Right Way to do things, I edited the `/usr/lib` version of the file, and commented out that line. Sure enough, that changed things, but it still doesn't seem to be reading the `/etc/systemd` version. Once I commented it out, it start timing out after 90 seconds, which I guess must be the default.

As a temporary workaround, I've edited the `/usr/lib` version to be my desired 20 minutes, but ... this doesn't seem like the right way to do things.

Is `systemctl edit` supposed to be editing the version in `/etc/systemd/system`?
Is this the putatively correct way to do things?
Do I have to do something more than `systemctl daemon-reload`?

Open to any and all suggestions on The Right Way to do this.

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`systemctl daemon-reload` is telling systemd itself to reload changed unit configuration. Not the software started by the unit, in this case clamd.  (Despite the manual warning about this distinction, you are not the first be confused by it.)

Instead, use one of the unit commands, like `systemctl reload-or-restart clamd@.service`

> Is systemctl edit supposed to be editing the version in
> /etc/systemd/system?

Yes. The idea is that  /etc contains site-specific configuration, which overrides what the system package installed to /usr.

I would omit `--full` and create "drop-in" files with only the different options.  Avoids maintaining an entire copy of the unit.  For example `systemctl edit clamd@.service` edits a temporary file that will go somewhere like
`/etc/systemd/system/clamd@.service.d/override.conf` and might contain just the different `TimeoutStartSec=`.